# Preload Image Within DOM

Tags: javascript

Is there any such way possible to preload an image specifically within DOM, inside this code structure? This is what I'm trying to do. All help would be greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/mjnaaLk5/8/

**I want the code to go specifically inside of this part of the code**

```
 onclick=" 
var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
var player = document.getElementById('player2');
```

---

```
 onclick=" 
var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
var player = document.getElementById('player2');
  document.querySelector('#playButton2 .initial').style.display='none';
  document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='none';
  document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='none';
player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
playButton2.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px ), url(\'https://via.placeholder.com/266x266\')';
playButton2.style.padding = '94px 100px 94px 100px'; 
playButton2.style.cursor = 'pointer';
playButton2.style.border='3px solid #e77d19';
playButton2.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
playButton2.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'; 
document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='inline-block';
player.play();
} else {
playButton2.style.background = 'linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px ), url(\'https://via.placeholder.com/266x266\')';
playButton2.style.border='3px solid #e77d19';
playButton2.style.padding = '94px 100px 94px 100px'; 
playButton2.style.cursor = 'pointer';
playButton2.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
playButton2.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'; 
document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='inline-block';
player.pause();
}">
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the preloaded images?

FYI: You might find your code a bit easier to work with if you moved all that javascript to a function and called it from the onclick. And, shift the repeated style work to css class(s).

Comment: Nothing, I just want them to be preloaded so that they don't flicker causing a change over effect. https://jsfiddle.net/mjnaaLk5/8/

Answer (score 1):

What would you like to preload?

This is a list of things you can preload:

- audio: Audio file.
- document: An HTML document intended to be embedded inside a  or .
- embed: A resource to be embedded inside an  element.
- fetch: Resource to be accessed by a fetch or XHR request, such as an ArrayBuffer or JSON file.
- font: Font file.
- image: Image file.
- object: A resource to be embedded inside an  element.
- script: JavaScript file.
- style: Stylesheet.
- track: WebVTT file.
- worker: A JavaScript web worker or shared worker.
- video: Video file.

Leverage a `rel="preload"` tag attribute to achieve preloading.

In your code, I cant find elements that are "preloadable".

For preloading images you have multiple options:

Preload CSS then preload image using that CSS, set image as background.

```
#idOftagTOContainImage { background: url(http://domain.tld/image-01.png) no-repeat}
```

Pure JS preloading:

```
   function preload() {
        for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image()
            images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
        }
    }
    preload(
        "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
        "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
        "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"
    )
```

Preloading with AJAX calls:

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // XHR to request a JS and a CSS
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://domain.tld/preload.js');
        xhr.send('');
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://domain.tld/preload.css');
        xhr.send('');
        // preload image
        new Image().src = "http://domain.tld/preload.png";
    }, 1000);
};
```

EDIT: According to your specific Fiddle is this what you wanna?
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/he0paqn7/)

Since you already manage style, let's leverage that for preloading the image, simply point to correct image. Set up its size if you need, but it's best that image is of that size in 1st place (for good looks and small size).

```
style="display:block; width: 266px; height: 266px; cursor: pointer;background-color: black;background: url(\via.placeholder.com/266x266\) no-repeat;
```

EDIT: Just set whatever background you need to url(thatlocation);

Here is a new: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3y2r2p4/)

Comment: Look at last fiddle? Is that it?

Comment: This answer above doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to load them into JS objects when the page loads

```
    <script>
       Image1 = new Image();
       Image1.src = "/imgfolder/imagename1.gif"

       Image2 = new Image();
       Image2.src = "/imgfolder/imagename2.gif";
    </script>
```

Assuming you want to set them as the background image on the click functionality.....

```
if (player.paused) {
   //....other code
   playButton2.style.backgroundImage = Image1.src
}
else
{
   //....other code
   playButton2.style.backgroundImage = Image2.src
}
```